# Python - writing out the result of Popen into a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to write every line, I receive from this script, into a mysql table ? I want to have 2 columns: The ip-adress I need for the command (ipAdresse) and a part of the output of the command itself (I want to split some content of the output).. I do not want to ask for any code but I just want to know whether it's even possible to keep this code as it is and add some stuff to it or I have to rewrite it to get the results I want :)
Now I just write the output of the command into a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python import subprocess import commands
import subprocess

ipAdresse_4 = 0

datei = open("pointerRecord.txt", "w")

while (ipAdresse_4 < 255):
        ipAdresse_4 = ipAdresse_4 + 1
        ipAdresse = '82.198.205.%d' % (ipAdresse_4,)
        subprocess.Popen("host %s" % ipAdresse, stdout=datei, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example using sqlite3, with minimal changes you can make it work with mysql

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.isolation_level = None
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE ipaddr (ip text, val text )''')

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for ip in [ '173.194.43.34', '17.172.224.47', '198.252.206.16' ]:
    pipe = Popen('host {}'.format( ip ), shell=True, stdout=PIPE )
    for line in pipe.stdout:
        cur.execute ( "INSERT INTO ipaddr VALUES ('{}','{}')".format( ip, line.strip( ) ))
```

and you can pull the data out of the table by:

```
cur.execute( 'SELECT * FROM ipaddr' ).fetchall( )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run following mysql query -

```
sqlquery = "insert into table values (%s, subprocess.Popen('host %s', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate[0])"%(ipAdresse_4, ipAdresse_4)
```